# Compute gaussian curvature K(x,y)

Tags: differential-geometry

Let  $S$ = {$(x,y)\in R^2 | x^2+y^2<1$ }  with the first fundamental form $ds^2 = \frac {4}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}{(dx^2+dy^2)}$

---

$ds^{2}=Edu^{2}+2Fdudv+Gdv^{2}$

E = G = $\frac {4}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}$ , F=0

$K={\frac  {\det {\mathrm  {I\!I}}}{\det {\mathrm  {I}}}}={\frac  {LN-M^{2}}{EG-F^{2}}},$

How to calculate Second Fundamental form??

Answer (score 1):

There is no second fundamental form when you have an abstract Riemannian manifold. (But there is nevertheless an intrinsic Gaussian curvature.) Only when your surface is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$ (or some other Riemannian manifold) is there a second fundamental form. The second fundamental form measures how the submanifold is twisting inside the bigger manifold.

At any rate, you should look for the formula for the Gaussian curvature *just* in terms of the first fundamental form. It's rather nice when $F=0$.